# Is there any extra-biblical evidence that the Ark of the Covenant was at Shiloh?

Tags: extra-biblical, archaeology, 1-samuel, ark-of-the-covenant

Is there any extra-Biblical evidence that the Ark of the Covenant resided at Shiloh during the time of 1 Samuel 4?